# How to get solve time using JuMP/GLPK

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I can't get the solve time and node count of a MIP model using JuMP, with GLPK. Using Gurobi it works fine. Here is a minimum example to reproduce the error I am getting:

```
using JuMP
using GLPKMathProgInterface

m = Model(solver=GLPKSolverMIP())
@variable(m, x, upperbound=1)
@objective(m, Max, x) 

solve(m)

println(getsolvetime(m))
```

I get the error:

> *ERROR: MethodError: no method matching getsolvetime(::GLPKMathProgInterface.GLPKInterfaceMIP.GLPKMathProgModelMIP)
>   Closest candidates are:   getsolvetime(::JuMP.Model) at
>   ~/.julia/v0.5/JuMP/src/JuMP.jl:205
>
>   getsolvetime(::MathProgBase.SolverInterface.LPQPtoConicBridge) at
>   ~/.julia/v0.5/MathProgBase/src/SolverInterface/lpqp_to_conic.jl:199
>
>   getsolvetime(::Int64) at
>   ~/.julia/v0.5/MathProgBase/src/SolverInterface/SolverInterface.jl:27
>
>   ...  in getsolvetime(::JuMP.Model) at
>   ~/.julia/v0.5/JuMP/src/JuMP.jl:208*

An equivalent message is shown when using the *getnodecount* method. I understand, from the documentation, that these functions are only available if implemented. Does this error mean they are not implemented? Is there a way to access any of this information going to the internal model?

Any directions are appreciated

Thank you.

Comment: That's correct, it's not implemented in GLPKMathProgInterface. If the GLPK API exposes a method to query the solve time, then it should be easy to expose through Julia. You can look at some of the other solver packages for examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that `solve_time(model)` is now possible.